# Using automatically created properties in the class

Tags: typescript

I am just learning `TypeScript` so this is a newb question, but Google and even SO failed to help.

Given this code:

```
class Student implements IPerson {
    public fullname: string = firstname + " " + middleinitial + " " + lastname;

    constructor(public firstname, public middleinitial, public lastname) {
        // this.fullname = firstname + " " + middleinitial + " " + lastname;
    }
}

function greeter(person: IPerson) {
    return "Hello, " + person.fullname;
}
```

when I try to assign to `fullname` in the initial declaration:

```
public fullname: string = firstname + " " + middleinitial + " " + lastname;
```

`TypeScript` is saying that `firstname`, `middleinitial` and `lastname` don't exist, yet somehow, the compiled code works as expected. What am I doing wrong here? I understand I can assign the auto gen props in the `constructor` (as is shown in the comment) but that is not always what I need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access a property in the current class, you have to prefix it with `this`.

```
public fullname: string = this.firstname + " " + this.middleinitial + " " + this.lastname;
```

It works without using `this` inside the constructor because the parameters have those names.